# SwfitUI List Make Scrolling disabled

Tags: swift, swiftui

Is there a way to make List in SwiftUI non scrollable?

like we have

> tableView.isScrollEnabled

Comment: You could use `ForEach`

Comment: @Andrew using forEach?

Comment: This is a good description of `ForEach` https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-create-views-in-a-loop-using-foreach

Comment: thank you got it working with your comment, actually already using foreach within list 

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### iOS 16+

There is now a modifier called `scrollDisabled(_:)` that will disable scrolling.  You can read more about it in Apple's documentation: [scrollDisabled(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/scrolldisabled(_:))

You use it in the following way.

```
List {

}.scrollDisabled(true)
```

### iOS 15 and below

Instead of using `List` which is scrollable, use `ForEach`.

`ForEach` is not scrollable by default.

Here is an example using `ForEach`

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let colors: [Color] = [.red, .green, .blue]

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(colors, id: \.self) { color in
                Text(color.description.capitalized)
                    .padding()
                    .background(color)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

A good resource for `ForEach` can be found [here](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-create-views-in-a-loop-using-foreach) similarly one for `List` can be found [here](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/working-with-lists).

---

## Update

There are currently two ways to stop a `List` from scrolling:

- Using `UITableView.appearance().isScrollEnabled = false` (but this can unintended side-effects)
- Using the 3rd party dependency [Introspect](https://github.com/siteline/SwiftUI-Introspect)

### Caveats

#### `List` contained in a `NavigationView`

If your `List` is contained in a `NavigationView` then it will still scroll. Neither of the above methods stop it from scrolling.

Here is an example view:

```
import SwiftUI
import Introspect

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(0..<10, id: \.self) { _ in
                    NavigationLink("Tap") {
                        Text("Hello").onTapGesture {
                            print("hello")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
//            .onAppear {
//                UIScrollView.appearance().isScrollEnabled = false
//            }
//            .introspectTableView { tableView in
//                tableView.isScrollEnabled = false
//            }
        }
    }
}
```

Uncommenting the `onAppear` or the `introspectTableView` does not stop the `List` from scrolling.

#### `List` not contained in a `NavigationView`

If the `List` is not contained in a `NavigationView` then we can be possible to stop the `List` from scrolling.

If we remove the `NavigationView` from the above example, we can see that by uncommenting the `onAppear` or the `introspectTableView` the `List` does stop scrolling.

Here is a [video](https://i.imgur.com/TxaYNAv.mp4) of the above situations.

Answer (score 12):

**In iOS 16**, you can do that by adding [`.scrollDisabled(true)`](https://sarunw.com/posts/disable-scrolling-swiftui/).

```
List {
    // ...
}
.scrollDisabled(true)
```

Answer (score 11):

This is my extension, to disable scrolling on `List`.

```
extension View {
    
    func hasScrollEnabled(_ value: Bool) -> some View {
        self.onAppear {
            UITableView.appearance().isScrollEnabled = value
        }
    }
}
```

Example:

```
List {
    ...
}
.hasScrollEnabled(false)
```

Don't forget `.onDisappear { UITableView.appearance().isScrollEnabled = true }`

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, since it keeps the List

Comment: Unfortunately, this seems also to be affecting other lists in the same NavigationView.

Comment: This didn't work for me

Answer (score 8):

There isn't an elegant solution to this until iOS 16 and above, where you can use .scrollDisabled(true)

Otherwise, the only thing that worked for me was adding .simultaneousGesture(DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0), including: .all) to the list.

Comment: This deserves more upvotes! Very useful if using < iOS 16

Comment: Only thing here that worked for me while supporting iOS 15

Comment: I would give this 10 upvotes, if I could!

Comment: Does not work on macOS.

Answer (score 5):

Simplifying YannSteph's answer:

```
List {
    ...    
}
.onAppear {
    UITableView.appearance().isScrollEnabled = false
}
```

Comment: This works great - however a side effect is that it applies to ALL Lists in the ContentView. Which is OK for my application, but it seems it should only affect the List you apply it to

Comment: Doesn't work to me

Answer (score 4):

While using a VStack + ForEach kinda does the trick, one of the shortcoming is that when clicking on a row, the click feedback is not what you would expect for a tableview anymore (the background does not highlight), so it might not be an appropriate solution based on UX expectations.

Another way to achieve this is by using this third party library :

https://github.com/siteline/SwiftUI-Introspect

and then you can do

```
List {
    // ...
}
.introspectTableView { tableView in
                         tableView.isScrollEnabled = false
                     }
```

Answer (score 3):

If you need to use a `List` (e.g. for selection), what works best for me (instead of disabling scrolling for all Lists) is to set the height of the list programatically:

```
List(items){ item in Text(item.title)}.frame(
  height: CGFloat(items.count) * CGFloat(ROW_HEIGHT)
)
```

This way the list won't scroll since it's set to the height it needs to show all items.

Comment: This works very well, but, the problem here is the row height. How can you get it? Keep in mind, that any fixed value does not work, because of accessibility fonts, various langugages etc.

Answer (score 3):

Lets use @ViewBuilder

```
extension View {
@ViewBuilder
func disableListScroll() -> some View {
    if #available(iOS 16.0, *) {
        self
        .scrollDisabled(true)
    } else {
        self
        .simultaneousGesture(DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0), including: .all)
    }
}}
```

Then you can use it on list by calling

```
.disableListScroll()
```

So you can achieve beast solution for iOS 16+ and workaround for targets under iOS 16.

Workaround from [Elliott Davies](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5485180/elliott-davies) response.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to not disable scrolling for all Lists do this:

```
List{
 Text("Test")
}
.onAppear { UITableView.appearance().isScrollEnabled = false }
.onDisappear{ UITableView.appearance().isScrollEnabled = true }
```

Answer (score -6):

I'm pretty sure this also disables the content but you can do:

```
List {
    // ...
}.disabled(true)
```

ScrollView API is very lacking in SwiftUI so you might want to use a `UIViewRepresentable`.

Comment: No that would also disable action on list which i don't want only scroll should be disabled