# List hides when adding in ScrollView SwiftUI

Tags: ios, list, scrollview, swiftui

I have added a `List` inside the `ScorllView` but it's not showing in canvas after adding inside to `ScrollView`

here is my code

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack {
                Text("My List")
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .fontWeight(.bold)

                List(0 ..< 5) { item in
                    Text("Hello World")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: sw]

Comment: Why are you doing this at first place ? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini This is just a sample app I have created, We can also add few other View inside the VStack
My concern is in storyboard we can achieve this but why can't in SwiftUI

Comment: I know, I just wanted to know how you like to see the list? fill? fit? custom? I have covered all of them in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58969900/5623035), check it out.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

## The Issue:

That is because `List` infer it size from its parent `View`. So when you embed it inside something like `VStack` that have dynamic height, it can't infer it size correctly.

## Solutions:

You have some options here:

## 1. Size `List` to match it's content  Automatically (Perfect)

You can use `ForEach` directly instead of using `List`, then you have more control over the content size

```
ForEach(0 ..< 5) { item in
    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
        Text("Hello World").frame(height: 42)
        Divider()
    }.padding(.horizontal, 8)
}
```

<sub>You can change all sizes and spacings according to your needs</sub>

---

## 2. Size `List` to match it's content  manually (Good but not perfect)

Give it a static frame like the way you do in `UIKit` by setting the `.frame()` modifier on the `List`:

```
List(0 ..< 5) { item in
    Text("Hello World")
}.frame(height: 224)
```

<sub>You can use `GeometryReader` to find the exact size of the parent and apply it to the `List`</sub>

---

## 3. Just show the `List` (Not good but it works)

add `.scaledToFill()` modifier to `List`

Comment: I am using `scaledToFill` and it works fine. Why is not considered "good?

Comment: How can scaledToFill be combined with a list where scrolling is disabled? The list is visible, but not at full height.

Answer (score 8):

I assume you expected the following:

```
var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { geometry in
        ScrollView {
           VStack {
               Text("My List")
                   .font(.largeTitle)
                   .fontWeight(.bold)

                List {
                    ForEach(0 ..< 50) { item in // 50 for testing
                        Text("Hello World")
                    }
                }
            }
            .frame(height: geometry.size.height)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many reasons, why you might need a List in a ScrollView. Mine is, that I have a form, where one of the rows is a grid of images, each with a contextMenu. ContextMenu does not work in a List Row with grid content. So, this row can not be in a List. And I have other rows, where I need swipe actions. Which do not work outside of the List. That's why I have to use a List, within a ScrollView. Combining these responses  https://stackoverflow.com/a/68789867/1379833, https://stackoverflow.com/a/60758138/1379833 with GeometryReader I got it to work.

```swift
import Introspect

@State private var tableViewContentHeight: CGFloat = 0

var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { screenGeometryReader in
        ScrollView {
            ... // content of the scrollView
            List {
                ... // content of the list
            }
            .introspectTableView { tableView in
                tableViewContentHeight = tableView.contentSize.height
            }
            .frame(
                width: screenGeometryReader.size.width, 
                height: tableViewContentHeight
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Introspect is a 3rd party library from https://github.com/siteline/SwiftUI-Introspect

Comment: This is not working.

Comment: This has stopped working in Xcode 14 :(