# How to disable scroll but keep user interactivity

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, scrollview

I have a Canvas inside of a List. When I start to draw, Swift thinks I'm scrolling and treats drawing gestures as scrolling gestures. How to disable scroll, but keep user interactivity active?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58836261/swfitui-list-make-scrolling-disabled

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.